# Error upon creating tables in sqlplus

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus

I'm new to sqlplus and was trying to run a sql script that creates a few tables, but once I try to run it, it gives me an error saying that the table or view doesnt exist and I dont know how to fix this error.
My script is:

```
 drop table Borrower;
 create table Borrower (
     bid char(100) not null, 
     password char(100) not null, 
     name char(100) null, 
     address char(100) null, 
     phone char(100) null, 
     emailAddress char(100) null, 
     sinOrStNo char(100) null, 
     expiryDate date null, 
     --type ENUM('student','faculty','staff'),
     type char(100) not null,
     --CONSTRAINT Btype_check CHECK (type IN ('student','faculty','staff')),
     FOREIGN KEY (type) references BorrowerType(type),
     PRIMARY KEY (bid));
 grant select on Borrower to public;
```

Comment: Could be the `drop table Borrower` command - you're trying to drop a table which doesn't exists

Comment: No i tried it. it still fails to create the data base.

Comment: The DB or the Table? what happens if you run only the `create` command ?

Comment: what table did the error specified? if the referenced table `borrowerType` does not exist???

Comment: Can you try executing the commands one by one. First run drop table Borrower then create table command and then grant commands. Pass on the exact point of error and message

Comment: it says: unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys

Comment: Please always post the _actual_ error when you get one. Just saying that there is an error relies on other people guessing what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "unique/primary keys in table referenced by foreign keys "

Data integrity is crucial to a properly run database so Oracle will not let us drop a table if its primary key is referenced by another table's foreign key.  So it hurls ORA-02449.

So, given this set up:

```
create table t_parent (
    id number not null
    , constraint tp_pk primary key (id)
);
create table t_child (
    id number not null
    , p_id number not null 
    , constraint tc_pk primary key (id)
    , constraint tc_tp_fk foreign key (p_id)
        references t_parent (id)
);
```

There are three ways to drop table `t_parent`.

1. run `drop table t_child` first: no child table, no foreign key.
2. Remove the blocking foreign key: `alter table t_child drop constraint tc_pc_fk`.
3. A variant on the previous one, let the database figure out the foreign keys: 
     `drop table t_parent cascade constraints`.

The first option is the most proper, because it leaves the database in a valid state (no tables, no possibility of data integrity corruption).  The valid use for the third approach is a script which razes all the tables from a schema: it's easy to generate such a script  from the data dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The order that you drop or create tables are important because if you have foreign keys referencing another table, you cant delete that table before deleting your own table.
In this example, the Borrower table has to be dropped before the BorrowerType table.